# Alterar variável de outra classe

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Tenho duas activity/classes, segue o botao da minha primeira activity onde quando eu clico vai para a segunda activity:

```
    public void onButtonClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Busuarios){
        Intent i = new Intent(Velocimetro.this,Usuarios.class);
        i.putExtra("vel",maxima);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Agora dentro da minha segunda activity tenho o seguinte:

```
        Intent i = getIntent();
    velm = i.getDoubleExtra("vel",Math.round(vel.maxima));
```

O que eu preciso: Nessa segunda activity eu preciso ALTERAR o valor da váriavel MÁXIMA (lá da primeira activity).

Como eu faço?

Comment: Não entendi bem, você quer alterar a variável que está na outra activity?

Comment: Dei um edit para melhor responder.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 4):

Duas formas. A primeira é setar a variável **maxima** como *public static* e alterá-la diretamente de qualquer outra classe: Velocimetro.maxima = valor;

Ou

**método ActivityForResult()**
Sua primeira Activity chama a segunda e aguarda um resultado.

Por exemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Velocimetro.this, 
Usuarios.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Na sua segunda Activity seleciona o dado que deseja retornar para a primeira Activity.

Por exemplo, na Activity Usuarios.class:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("resultado", resultado);
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Para não retornar dados:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent); 
finish();
```

**Recebendo o resultado**

Agora na sua primeira Activity escreva o seguinte código no método *onActicityResult()*:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == 1) { 
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
         String result = data.getStringExtra("resultado");
     }
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) { 
//vazio
    }
 }
 }//onActivityResult
```

Comment: Deu certo usando a variável public static. Valeu!

Comment: Disponha,  bons códigos!