# java.lang.NullPointerException: botão retornando null

Tags: android, android-activity

Bom Dia,

Como faço para referenciar um botão de outra activity?
No main, estou usando outro layout para inflar minha lista, e o evento do botão está obviamente retornando nulo pq nao está encontrando a view.
Help.

```
private static String pesquisarDadosLivro;
private DadosLivrosAdapter adapter;

private static final String GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=  " + pesquisarDadosLivro;

private static final int DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);     

    Button pesquisarLivro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pesquisar);
    pesquisarLivro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText dadosLivro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dados_livro);
            pesquisarDadosLivro = dadosLivro.getText().toString();
            //Log.v("MainActivity", "Texto a ser pesquisado " + pesquisarDadosLivro);
        }
    });

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    adapter = new DadosLivrosAdapter(this, new ArrayList<DadosLivro>());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER, null, this);
}

@Override
public android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    // Create a new loader for the given URL
    return new DadosLivrosLoader(this, GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader, List<DadosLivro>
        informacoesLivros) {

    if (informacoesLivros != null && !informacoesLivros.isEmpty()) {
        adapter.addAll(informacoesLivros);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader) {
    adapter.clear();
}
```

}

Olá, consegui resolver o problema inflando a activity principal mesmo, como ela contem os componentes que interage com o usuário e é apenas 1 unica tela, achei mais viável, porém estou com outro erro, minha requisição http retornou 400, o valor informado pelo usuário não está enviando a URL, preciso que o Loader seja carregado após o evento do botão, sabe como posso fazer isso?

```
package com.example.android.listadelivros;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderCallbacks<List<DadosLivro>> {

    private String pesquisarDadosLivro;
    private DadosLivrosAdapter mAdapter;

    private  String GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL = null;

    private static final int DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button pesquisarLivro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pesquisar);
        pesquisarLivro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText dadosLivro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dados_livro);
                pesquisarDadosLivro = dadosLivro.getText().toString();
                GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL =
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q= " + pesquisarDadosLivro;

                final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.initLoader(DADOSLIVROS_ID_LOADER, null,);

            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

        mAdapter = new DadosLivrosAdapter(this, new ArrayList<DadosLivro>());

        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        return new DadosLivrosLoader(this, GOOGLE_LIVROS_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader, List<DadosLivro>
            informacoesLivros) {

        if (informacoesLivros != null && !informacoesLivros.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(informacoesLivros);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<List<DadosLivro>> loader) {
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: A ideia é que você não referencie uma View de uma Activity em outra Activity. Caso você queira utilizar uma informação de outra Activity, você precisa fazer a comunicação entre elas: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html .

Comment: Eu acredito que esta resposta possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135889/2461

Comment: É necessário que o botão esteja declaro no xml que você setou como **contentView** ( setContentView(R.layout.list_view) ), como disse o Erick, não é possível referenciar uma Activity em outra!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Aline

O que você pretende fazer infelizmente não é possível. Uma `View` só existe após uma Activity inflá-la(instanciar, fazer existir...) através do método `setContentView(int layout)` e passar a manipulá-la. Uma `Activity` não consegue manipular de qualquer maneira a `View` de outra `Activity`.

Eu tenho duas soluções possíveis, e que a escolha dependerá de como está o seu projeto como um todo.

**1- Trabalhar com `Fragments` e fazer com que as interações no fragmento sejam enviadas a `Activity` para que ela manipule.**

Para começarmos, a ideia é que sua `Activity` implemente uma interface que o `Fragment` conheça e chame. Então, vamos criar a tal interface que será chamada quando houve o click no fragment:

```
public interface OnFragmentButtonClickListener  {
    public void onButtonClick();
}
```

E vamos então fazer com que a Activity herde dessa interface e implemente o método:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends AppCompact implements OnFragmentButtonClickListener {

    //... Outros métodos comuns da Activity

    public void onButtonClick() {
       //O botão do fragment foi clicado, faça o que tem que fazer na activity!
    }

}
```

Certo, no método `onAttach()` do seu fragment , que é chamado durante o ciclo de vida do fragment quando uma o fragment é anexado a `Activity`, capture a `Activity` usando polimorfismo para termos em mãos uma instância dê `OnFragmentButtonClickListener`. Dessa forma:

```
public void FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

   OnFragmentButtonClickListener onFragmentButtonClickListener

   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        if(context instanceof OnFragmentButtonClickListener) {
            onFragmentButtonClickListener = (OnFragmentButtonClickListener) context;
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    //Métodos comuns ao fragment
}
```

Agora, no `onClickListener` do seu button chame a interface que é implementada pela `Activity` para que assim a `Activity` possa corresponder ao click no fragment:

```
fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //onFragmentButtonClickListener.onButtonClick(); Lembrando que onFragmentButtonClickListener pode ser null caso a activity não implemente a interface.
    } 
});
```

**2- Uma Activity transferir o evento a outra Activity através de `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int FLAG)`.**

O que ocorre é que uma Activity B é aberta pela Activity A, que fica aguardando algum retorno da Activity B. A Activity B só existe para que interações aconteçam e assim encerre seu ciclo de vida retornando algo a Activity A. O que podemos fazer é fazer a Activity A abrir a Activity B e, quando o botão X for clicado, encerrar a vida da Activity B retornando a Activity A um indicativo de que o botão foi clicado. Não sei se isso se encaixa no contexto de projeto que você tem e **nem acredito que seja uma solução elegante**, mas vamos lá.

Na Activity A, você abrirá a Activity B não através do método `startActivitiy(Intent intent)`, mas através de `startActivityForResult(Intent, FLAG)`.

Ao iniciar a ActivityB, informamos a flag de retorno:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
int flagRetorno = 55;
startActivityForResult(intent, flagRetorno);
```

Quando houver o clique no botão da Activity B, poderemos informar guardar de alguma forma que ele foi clicado e, quando formos finalizar a Activity B, poderemos informar a Activity A que ele foi clicado assim:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("botaoclicado", true);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Mas como vou receber isso na Activity A? Através do método`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` que faz parte do ciclo de vida da `Activity`.

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == flagRetorno) { 
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
             boolean botaoFoiClicado = data.getStringExtra("botaoclicado");
         }
     }
}
```

**Reafirmo que não acredito que seja a solução mais elegante e até mesmo funcional para o seu caso**, mas fica como algo a se pensar e de repente ser usado caso você analise melhor sua estrutura do projeto.

Att,

Comment: Olá, consegui resolver o problema inflando a activity principal mesmo, como ela contem os componentes que interage com o usuário e é apenas 1 unica tela, achei mais viável, porém estou com outro erro, minha requisição http retornou 400, o valor informado pelo usuário não está enviando a URL, preciso que o Loader seja carregado após o evento do botão, sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia criar uma pergunta específica para este erro? Assim mais pessoas podem lhe ajudar, e facilita para outros usuários possam se beneficiar da sua pergunta!

Comment: Aline, interessante seu novo problema. Concordo com o Thiago, melhor criar uma outra pergunta para ter melhor possibilidade de expor o problema. Isso seria bem interessante. Que tal?